# Encoded url gives dangerous request exception

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, security, url, encoding

I send by AJAX request to get users. Search is input entered by user on the form. Url which is send doesn't contain illegar chars. (I know that chars like ' or < or > are incorrect for email adress)

```
GET http://localhost:1294/Users/GetAll?search=%27test%27%2B%3Cinfo%2540test.pl%3E
```

query is encoded to protect XSS, but I get exception:

```
A potentially dangerous Request.QueryString value was detected 
from the client (search="...test' <test@test.pl>").
```

I don't understand why I get this exception despite I encoded data in url ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using `<>` that is considered harmful even though it has been encoded before.

[MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh882339%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

> Request validation throws this exception when any HTML markup is detected, including harmless markup like `<b>` (bold) elements.